# Howto use lib-noir stateful-sessions in Compojure

Tags: web-applications, clojure, compojure, noir

I think I have a fairly straightforward problem here. But I've been looking at this screen too long. So I'm trying (and failing) to get stateful sessions working in Compojure. The refheap code paste **[is here](https://www.refheap.com/paste/11161)**.

You can see me trying to use [**lib-noir**](https://github.com/noir-clojure/lib-noir) (line 62) to initialize stateful sessions. Then when the app is running, I try to make a call to [**session/put!**](http://www.luminusweb.net/noir-api/noir.session.html#var-put%21) some data in the session (line 43).

Now, this stacktrace says that in session.put!, lib-noir is trying to swap out a session var that hasn't been bound. Now, I thought I did that on line 62. So I'm sure this is a simple fix that another set of eyes will see.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: clojure.lang.Var$Unbound cannot be cast to clojure.lang.Atom                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
        at clojure.core$swap_BANG_.invoke(core.clj:2110)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        at noir.session$put_BANG_.invoke(session.clj:18)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        at bkell.http.handler$fn__6159.invoke(handler.clj:156)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
        at compojure.core$make_route$fn__3800.invoke(core.clj:93)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
        at compojure.core$if_route$fn__3784.invoke(core.clj:39)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
        at compojure.core$if_method$fn__3777.invoke(core.clj:24)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
        at compojure.core$routing$fn__3806.invoke(core.clj:106)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
        at clojure.core$some.invoke(core.clj:2390)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
        at compojure.core$routing.doInvoke(core.clj:106)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:139)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
        ...
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem? I've been facing the same issue and started a thread, but didn't get any responses either.

Answer (score 2):

Answered by James Reeves at - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/compojure/yG6nCXiEinU

> Try swapping around handler/site and wrap-noir-session*. Because
>   handler/site applies the wrap-session middleware, and
>   wrap-noir-session* depends on that according to the documentation,
>   handler/site should be applied before wrap-noir-session.
>
> - James

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `wrap-noir-session`, not `wrap-noir-session*`. The documentation on `wrap-noir-session*` says (my emphasis) "A stateful layer around wrap-session. **Expects that wrap-session has already been used.**"

If you want to use `wrap-noir-session*` I think you'll need to use [`wrap-session`](https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring/blob/master/ring-core/src/ring/middleware/session.clj#L55) explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Yeah, I definitely tried both with and without the asterix. I even tried removing the call to friend/authenticate. So the app def looks like: `(def app (handler/site (session/wrap-noir-session* app-routes))`. But I still get the same **Var$Unbound** error. So basically, some session atom is not getting bound when I call wrap-noir-session. So I'm looking for the right incantation.

Answer (score 0):

Putting down my answer as I keep coming to this question and forgetting it's been solved.

```
(ns my-project.handler
    (:require (compojure [handler :as handler]
                         [route :as route]
                         [core :refer :all])
              [noir.util.middleware :as middleware]
              [noir.session :as session]))

(defroutes my-routes
  (GET "/put" req (session/put! :test "yes"))
  (GET "/get" req (session/get :test))
  (route/resources "/")
  (route/not-found "Not Found"))

(def app
  (-> 
   (handler/site my-routes)
    session/wrap-noir-flash ; only if you need flash-put! and flash-get
    session/wrap-noir-session))
```