# Compojure Lib-Noir session/put! unbound var error

Tags: clojure

I am converting an older web app I made a few months ago from Noir to Compojure and I am using the Lib-Noir add-on. It appears that session/put! is either changed in some way I don't understand or it is bugging out for whatever reason.

Here, I can see that [4Clojure](https://www.4clojure.com/) appears to be using it with no problems: [See Line 51](https://github.com/4clojure/4clojure/blob/develop/src/foreclojure/login.clj). I also found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14806063/howto-use-lib-noir-stateful-sessions-in-compojure) that covers the same question but there doesn't appear to be a satisfactory response.

This should work [(Noir)](http://www.webnoir.org/tutorials/sessions/):

```
user=> (require '[noir.session :as sesh])
nil
user=> (sesh/put! :user "me")
ClassCastException clojure.lang.Var$Unbound cannot be cast to clojure.lang.Atom  
clojure.core/swap! (core.clj:2162)
```

The above is the same error that I am looking at on the webpage. Basically I'm stuck.

**Edit to add**

Appears I created a bit of confusion with the command line part: (put!) is not working in the program either. There's not much to write about it, except that it is (shesh/put! :uname user) and it appears that :uname isn't working. I'm confused as to why it would have worked before and not now when I am using the same tools as before. This is a rewrite of a site I build about 6 months ago. I'm just moving it to Compojure from Noir. The lib-noir session is, as far as I know, essentially the same as what was in Noir.

**ANOTHER EDIT**

I put the code up on github. This isn't the completed project, but hopefully someone can decipher what is going on here: https://github.com/dt1/SoloResume

Answer (score 1):

If you run it from the REPL, there is no browser session registered in Noir. You can simulate this by using binding:

```
(binding [sesh/*noir-session* (atom {:somekey "somevalue"})]
  (sesh/put! :user "borkdude"))
```

Use this only for testing/simulating to see what goes on in the session map, not in production code.

Comment: CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve var: noir.session/*session* in this context, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:1:1)

Comment: 't was a typo: *noir-session*

Comment: I breifly considered putting that in the raw program somewhere, but then I realized that somekey wouldn't be mutable so there doesn't appear to be any way to make it so that multiple peole can log in, is that about right? Plus how would I call it from other namespaces?

Comment: @dizzystar Atoms are mutable references to immutable data. The map it contains is immutable, but you can replace it by another immutable map. This is exactly what `put!` and `swap!` do.

Comment: Don't use my example in real code. Use it only for testing functions that must alter the session map, to see if they act as expected.

Answer (score 0):

A fairly old question, but answering here as it was the first Google result when I had the same problem. I was using compojure:1.1.6, ring:1.2.1 and lib-noir:0.7.6

You need to use noir.session/wrap-noir-session when defining your app - e.g:

```
(def app
  (-> (handler/site (routes app-routes ))
      session/wrap-noir-session
      wrap-base-url))
```

References:
https://groups.google.com/d/msg/clojure/XXgSGhF912I/luhN9wmMoi8J